# Too many redirects on AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, appharbor

I started getting this error on my application in AppHarbor. On localhost there is no problem.

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

I have recently added some code in `App_Code` directory, I am not sure if that is causing the problem or not.

Has anyone had any problems like this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the problem was the app_code. i turned off custom errors. and it was giving

> App_Code is not allowed because the application is precompiled...

solved it by disabling the precompile option in the apphb application settings.